# Handle oauth errors with Google Ruby Client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, google-api

I'm using Google API Ruby Client (gem 'google-api-client') in a Rails Web app, and I'd like to know how to catch specific errors in the oauth flow. In particular, what should I look for in the rescue statement? Here's the function called by the redirect after the user authorizes:

```
require 'google/api_client'

def google_auth_finish
  begin 
    client = Google::APIClient.new
    client.authorization.client_id = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    client.authorization.client_secret = GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    ...
  rescue ## WHAT GOES HERE TO IDENTIFY THE ERROR?
    # Handle the error
    logger.info "There was an error." 
  end 
end
```

Is there a reference somewhere with defined errors? I've searched and can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was asked years ago, but I literally just encountered this problem and happened upon this question.  You were just missing a small part.  This worked for me.  I am still relatively new, but in my case it prevented the program from breaking and printed out the error message, then the program continued on.

```
rescue Exception => error
      puts "Error #{error}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try [these](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html)Raising An Exception

Comment: My question is specifically about errors raised by Google::APIClient and how to specify them.